# How can I add some Text with Dynamic controls in asp:table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a dynamic table who have some textboxes in some cells.

Textboxes are also dynamic controls which are added from backend as :

```
chk = (CheckBox)tbl_fundtype.Rows[0].Cells[i].FindControl(DynamicChkID);
TableCell td = new TableCell();
if (chk.Checked == true)
{
   TextBox txt = new TextBox();
   txt.ID = "txt_" + dt_fundtype.Rows[i]["fund_type_cd"].ToString();
   txt.Attributes.Add("Placeholder", "Enter Share Percent...");
   td.Controls.Add(txt);
}
else
{
   td.Text = "     ";
}
tr.Cells.Add(td);
}
tbl_fundtype.Rows.Add(tr);
```

Here is the snapshot after adding the textbox in td :

[image]

Now I want the percent sign (%) next to the textbox.
I've tried td.Text but it didn't print any text.

How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT  :**

I also tried this :

```
if (chk.Checked == true)
                {
                    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                    txt.ID = "txt_" + dt_fundtype.Rows[i]["fund_type_cd"].ToString();
                    txt.Attributes.Add("Placeholder", "Enter Share Percent...");
                    td.Controls.Add(txt);
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = "%";
                    td.Controls.Add(lbl);
                }
```

still no change.didn't print any thing

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `label` after `textbox` in td

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "%";
td.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Comment: No,didn't print any thing :(

Comment: Just add the above code along with your existing code

Comment: if condition is working fine :/ that's why there is a textbox instead a blank area

Comment: i have tried same code and it is working fine i guuess you need to increase with of `td`. Also inspect the `td` in browser to see if label is added or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113719/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-alina-anjum).